# Stretching a drawable to fit ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, stretch

So I'm trying to have the "title" of my navigation drawer (implemented as ListView with custom adapter) contain an ImageView only. Problem is, after I try to load the image it never stretches properly and there's always a gap between the image and the borders, no matter how large the image I pick is (tried a 3200*2400, 1.64MB image in the screenshot). Am I not supposed to save the image as an image asset in the drawable folder, maybe?

Code:

```
int[] images = {... R.drawable.titleImage ...};

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.TitleImageView);
imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/TitleImageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot (image on top left, showing bounds to emphasise the imageView):

**EDIT:** I have tried to add my image again and realised that I added it the first time as an icon launcher  - could this be the cause? How do I add an image so that it'll be in a proper size (and does it matter if it's JPG or PNG?)

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's help you: imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Comment: tried that, unfortunately doesn't help at all (unless I put it after the FIT_XY and then the image is small in the middle)

Comment: Show the layout to which `R.id.TitleImageView` belongs.

Comment: I have added some other stuff to the project and it seems that the same problem happens with an ImageButton - I try to stretch a round icon to a round button but there's a radius difference (so it doesn't really fill it)

Comment: If it helps, when I set the ScaleType to CenterCrop the image stretched over the top (so it reached the top bound of the imageView and was cut). I have a feeling that I might have added it wrongly

Comment: I think problem is in your parent layout height. Change it to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. It was the way I added the image - I clicked on "add image asset", and added it as a launcher icon (I know, I know, but I'm a noob); obviously it made it too small to stretch somehow. When I copy-pasted the image to all of the drawable folders (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) it worked.

I assume that the same problem applies to my ImageButton - but for some reason, as you can see, the icons in the navigation drawer worked perfectly.